# Error when creating any vector with package::prob in R

Tags: r

I just need to create a simple vector like `x<-c(2, 4, 9, 12)`, but after running `library(prob)`, all I get is `Error in c(2, 4, 9, 12) : unused argument(s) (9,12)`. R seems to only take the first two arguments, and even if I try to create a vector with two entries it only assigns the value `NULL` as opposed to the actual vector. I can only replicate this issue on one computer, however.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a function `c` defined in `prob`. What is the result of `getAnywhere('c')`

Answer (score 0):

Something very pathological is occurring. When I install package:prob_0.9-2 in R 2.15.2 I get no error and the "x" variable appears normally constructed. You should restart and see if this persists and if it does you should reinstall R.